# How to play .pls file in android

Tags: android

Can anyone give me the **sample code for parsing and playing .pls** file in **android**?

[playlist]
 NumberOfEntries=1
 File1=http://stream.radiosai.net:8002/

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the `.pls` file and read it to find the media file inside since `pls` is a playlist not a format.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for a solution for 2 days about this issue and I've finally found a radio player which you can implement into your code: https://github.com/iammert/RadioPlayerService that plays .pls files from a radio service link (such as: http://stream.radiosai.net:8002/ ).

However, that url on your question should work on the default MediaPlayer but if anyone ever encounters this problem with urls that contain a .pls file, then they should use a radio player that supports the encoding and format. 
 .